# To flat XML: How could we flat all the descendants of an xml and get a xmllist

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, xml-serialization

The aim is to get the flat xmllist out of an xml: each item of the xmllist would be a descendant (not just child) of the xml. This way I have all the nodes of an xml inside the xmllist.

For example:

```
XML=
<a >
  <b >
   <b1/>
   <b2>
     <c1 />
     <c2 />
   </b2>
  </b>
</a>

What I want is:

 <a />
 <b />
 <b1 />
 <b2 />
 <c1 />
 <c2 />
 <b2 />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons this task is more complicated than just iterating over `xml.descendants(*)`:

1. You can't simply use the items in the resulting XMLList, or clone them, because each would bring its children and sub-hierarchy - instead, you have to make a copy of each element along with its name and attributes, but omit everything else.  This is done easiest by appending the name and attributes to a String, and then using `new XML(String)` to create  XML elements.
2. You explicitly want the result to be an XMLList, which unlike Array or Vector has no methods to add or remove elements, and is therefore not easy to create and/or modify.  All the items need to be appended to a parent node first, and then `xml.children()` can be used to return an XMLList object.

I have put together a little program that will return the flat kind of structure you want, and includes attributes, as well.  However, that last `<b2 />` in your example result would be one more element than the source XML originally had - so I assume it got in there by mistake, and I have not included it in my solution.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class FlattenXML extends Sprite
    {
        private var _xml : XML = <a>
                <b>
                    <b1 />
                    <b2>
                        <c1 />
                        <c2 />
                    </b2>
                </b>
            </a>;

        public function FlattenXML ()
        {
            trace ( flatXMLList ( _xml ) );
        }

        private function flatXMLList ( xml : XML ) : XMLList
        {
            var root : XML = <all />;
            root.appendChild ( new XML ( flatNodeString ( xml ) ) );
            for each (var child:XML in _xml.descendants ( "*" ))
            {
                if (child.nodeKind () == "element") 
                     root.appendChild ( new XML ( flatNodeString ( child ) ) );
            }

            return root.children ();
        }

        private function flatNodeString ( xml : XML ) : String
        {
            var str : String = "<" + xml.name () + " ";
            for each ( var attr:XML in xml.attributes ()) 
                str += attr.name () + "=\"" + attr.valueOf () + "\" ";
            str += " />";
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

Mind that this example will not include any text nodes, because from your example, it didn't seem like it needed to.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
xml.descendants("*")
```

? That seems to me to fulfill your requirements, as each item of the returned xmlllist would be a descendant of the xml, and you would have all the (element) nodes of the xml inside the xmllist.

If you mean you need other nodes besides elements, please specify. Many people use "node" loosely to mean "element".

Comment: I have updated my question with an example: please note that xml.descendats(*) wouldnt give this kind of flat structure. I guess I would need to write a recursive UDF for this one? Thanks.

Comment: @user503510: OK. I now understand your requirements better. See weltraumpirat's answer.